# How to convert NodeJs response to nested json response

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, node.js, express

I am using Nodejs(ExpressJS) and my-SQL to create a rest API. I want my response like nested json object which will easy to read on my frontend . I tried with for loop , but it does not gave me proper result , is there any plugins available to format this response or is there any easy way to do this nested json response .

my sql query is

```
SELECT category.id as category_id, sub_category.id as subcategory_id, product.id as product_id, 
       category.name as category_name, sub_category.name as subcategory_name, 
       product.name as product_name 
FROM product 
JOIN sub_category ON product.sub_category_id = sub_category.id 
JOIN category ON sub_category.category_id = category.id 
ORDER BY category.id;
```

and I am getting the response is like

```
[
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 11,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product new"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 2,
"product_id": 3,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 2",
"product_name": "product 3"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 1,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "product 1"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 2,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "product 2"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 4,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product updated"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 6,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 8,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product new"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 9,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product new"
},
{
"category_id": 1,
"subcategory_id": 1,
"product_id": 10,
"category_name": "category 1",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 1",
"product_name": "New Product new"
},
{
"category_id": 2,
"subcategory_id": 3,
"product_id": 5,
"category_name": "category 2",
"subcategory_name": "sub category 3",
"product_name": "product 5"
}
]
```

I need like

```
[
    {
        "category_id" : 1,
        "category_name" : "product 1",
        "data":[
                {
                    "sub_category_id" : 1,
                    "sub_category_name" : "product 1",
                    "data":[
                        {
                            "product_id" : 1,
                            "product_name" : "product 1"  
                        },
                        {
                            "product_id" : 2,
                            "product_name" : "product 2" 
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sub_category_id" : 2,
                    "sub_category_name" : "subcategory 2",
                    "data":[
                        {
                            "product_id" : 3,
                            "product_name" : "product 3"  
                        },
                        {
                            "product_id" : 4,
                            "product_name" : "product 4" 
                        }
                    ]    
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "category_id" : 2 ,
        "category_name" : "category 2",
        "data":[
            {
                "sub_category_id" : 3,
                "sub_category_name" : "sub category 3",
                "data":[
                    {
                        "product_id" : 5,
                        "product_name" : "product 5"  
                    },
                    {
                        "product_id" : 6,
                        "product_name" : "product 6" 
                    }
                ]    
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

is there any plugin for that or can anyone help me with this . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below repl link, implemented with nested forEach but you can use recursion as well.

https://repl.it/@debasish_pothal/nested-json

Answer (score 0):

"Flat is better than nested" according to Python PEP20:) People rather struggle against the opposite task - they want to convert nested JSON data to flat structure to be able to easily manipulate the data. **Normalizr** is AFAIK most popular lib for this task.

If you really need it nested, it should be a matter of writing correct reduce function, I suggest to go this way.

Anyway - if you want to use third-party SW, this might be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-to-nested